# the most clean way to static_assert 3 or more items in oneline

Tags: c++11, union, sizeof, c11, static-assert

How to static_assert 3 items to be same at compile time like this.

```
union
{
    std::uint32_t   multibyte;
    std::uint8_t    bytes[4];
} test;

static_assert(sizeof(test) == sizeof(test.multibyte) == sizeof(test.bytes), "Union size mismatch.");
```

So of course the static_assert here fails because the last check will be 1 == 4. Is there more clean way besides

```
static_assert(sizeof(test.bytes) == sizeof(test.multibyte) && sizeof(test) == sizeof(test.bytes), "Union size mismatch.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a struct for that:

```
template<typename...> struct AllSame;

template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Args>
struct AllSame<Arg1, Arg2, Args...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(Arg1) == sizeof(Arg2) && AllSame<Arg1, Args...>::value;
};

template<typename Arg>
struct AllSame<Arg>
{
        static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Not tested, might contain errors.

Comment: It works, the `AllSame<Test, decltype(Test::multibyte), decltype(Test::bytes)>::value` returns me `true` and can be used inside a `static_assert` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) then by the following example you can `static_assert` instances too, if they can be used in a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool compare_sizes(T&&, Ts&&...) noexcept {
    using expand = int[];
    bool result = sizeof...(Ts) > 0;

    static_cast<void>(expand {
        0, (static_cast<void>(result &= (sizeof(Ts) == sizeof(T))), 0)...
    });
    return result;
}
```

Example of use with your `union { /* ... */ } test`:

```
static_assert(compare_sizes(test, test.multibyte, test.bytes), "Size mismatch.");
```

Note that variable declaration and use of `static_cast` statement are prohibited in a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function body until [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

Comment: Yeah this will fix the example by different design. What I am looking, if there is some compile time std::equal/memcmp alike solution..

Comment: @ckain, renewed my answer.